# How many types of FusionCharts Chart List

Tags: fusioncharts

many people have problem that change type : {{ chart type of Fusionchart }}, So.
 I just want to show how many types of charts available in FusionCharts XT Chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [image]    ![FusionCharts XT Chart List

```
Given below is the list of charts in FusionCharts XT along with their JavaScript chart alias.


Chart Type  JavaScript Chart Alias  Flash file (SWF Name)

Single Series Charts
Column 3D   Column3D    Column3D.swf
Column 2D   Column2D    Column2D.swf
Line 2D Line    Line.swf
Area 2D Area2D  Area2D.swf
Bar 2D  Bar2D   Bar2D.swf
Pie 2D  Pie2D   Pie2D.swf
Pie 3D  Pie3D   Pie3D.swf
Doughnut 2D Doughnut2D  Doughnut2D.swf
Doughnut 3D Doughnut3D  Doughnut3D.swf
Pareto 2D   Pareto2D    Pareto2D.swf
Pareto 3D   Pareto3D    Pareto3D.swf

Multi-series Charts
Multi-series Column 2D  MSColumn2D  MSColumn2D.swf
Multi-series Column 3D  MSColumn3D  MSColumn3D.swf
Multi-series Line 2D    MSLine  MSLine.swf
Multi-series Bar 2D MSBar2D MSBar2D.swf
Multi-series Bar 3D MSBar3D MSBar3D.swf
Multi-series Area 2D    MSArea  MSArea.swf
Marimekko   Marimekko   Marimekko.swf
Zoom Line   ZoomLine    ZoomLine.swf

Stacked Charts
Stacked Column 3D   StackedColumn3D StackedColumn3D.swf
Stacked Column 2D   StackedColumn2D StackedColumn2D.swf
Stacked Bar 2D  StackedBar2D    StackedBar2D.swf
Stacked Bar 3D  StackedBar3D    StackedBar3D.swf
Stacked Area 2D StackedArea2D   StackedArea2D.swf
Multi-series Stacked Column 2D  MSStackedColumn2D   MSStackedColumn2D.swf

Combination Charts
True 3D Chart (Multi-series 3D Single Y Combination chart - Column + Line + Area)   MSCombi3D   MSCombi3D.swf
Multi-series 2D Single Y Combination Chart (Column + Line + Area)   MSCombi2D   MSCombi2D.swf
Multi-series Column 3D + Multi-series Line - Single Y Axis  MSColumnLine3D  MSColumnLine3D.swf
Stacked Column2D + Line single Y Axis   StackedColumn2DLine StackedColumn2DLine.swf
Stacked Column3D + Line single Y Axis   StackedColumn3DLine StackedColumn3DLine.swf
Multi-series 2D Dual Y Combination Chart (Column + Line + Area) MSCombiDY2D MSCombiDY2D.swf
Multi-series Column 3D + Multi-series Line - Dual Y Axis    MSColumn3DLineDY    MSColumn3DLineDY.swf
Stacked Column 3D + Line Dual Y Axis    StackedColumn3DLineDY   StackedColumn3DLineDY.swf
Multi-series Stacked Column 2D + Line Dual Y Axis   MSStackedColumn2DLineDY MSStackedColumn2DLineDY.swf

XY Plot Charts
Scatter Chart   Scatter Scatter.swf
Bubble Chart    Bubble  Bubble.swf

Scroll Charts
Scroll Column 2D    ScrollColumn2D  ScrollColumn2D.swf
Scroll Line 2D  ScrollLine2D    ScrollLine2D.swf
Scroll Area 2D  ScrollArea2D    ScrollArea2D.swf
Scroll Stacked Column 2D    ScrollStackedColumn2D   ScrollStackedColumn2D.swf
Scroll Combination 2D (Single Y)    ScrollCombi2D   ScrollCombi2D.swf
Scroll Combination 2D (Dual Y)  ScrollCombiDY2D ScrollCombiDY2D.swf

Others
Single Series Grid Component    SSGrid  SSGrid.swf][2]
```

Source :  http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/setup/list-of-charts.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-setup-list-of-charts.html) you can find the complete list of charts for FusionCharts XT.